# Underline ie6-bug. Inline element in <a> tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, underline

There is a markup:

```
<a href="#">
    lorem ipsum<span>15</span>
</a>
```

There are styles:

```
a{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a span{
    background: #fff;  //To clean the bottom underlining under <span>
}
```

Works in all interesting me browsers. Except **IE6**. The bottom underlining under `<span>` **remains**.

How to solve this problem **without** changing a markup.

---

```
a span{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Does not work.

Comment: Could you post a link to the page? I suspect there's something else interfering with the styles here.

Comment: @Olly Hodgson , There is a problem. The site is on a local server. I will try to solve this problem.

Comment: In the near future I can not solve this problem.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this problem and I can reproduce it at IE7 and IE8 as well. Why are you complaining about IE6 only? Did you try the other IE versions as well? If it works over there for you, you'll really need to replace the code by a fullworthy SSCCE (from `<!doctype>`, `<html>` until with `</html>`) so that we can just copy'n'paste'run' it.

Comment: Did you solve this or is it still relevant?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your CSS to this:

```
a span {
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Despite what others have posted, `text-decoration: none;` does NOT work.

Comment: @Marlorn, Underlining does not disappear.

Comment: I take back my comment about `text-decoration: none;` not working.  Add it in and I believe it works.

Comment: It does not work for me. I do not know why. There can be any styles disturb.

Comment: I've tested this as well. For me, `background` + `display` makes it work in everything but IE6, and `text-decoration` makes it work in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try?

```
a span{
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I believe this works for all browsers?

---

Try adding `background: none;` to the existing CSS tag as shown above. I'll try and see if I can't get this to work on IE6.

Comment: Wrote even so: `text-decoration:none !important;` Does not work in IE6. Underlining does not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Might this work?

```
a{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a span{
    background: #fff;  //To clean the bottom underlining under <span>
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Wrote even so: `text-decoration:none !important;` Does not work in IE6. Underlining does not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Elite Gentleman's answer: Use a conditional statement (prefered) or the underscore hack for targeting IE6 only:

```
a span {
  _text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: @Boldewyn, But it does not change an essence. `text-decoration:none;` not works.

Comment: Do you have any side effects? IDs, background images, inline style declarations? Can you be sure, that it is an IE bug and not something inherited from somewhere else?

Comment: my styles works in: firefox 3.6.2, Chrome 5.0. Not works in: ie6, ie7, opera 10.0.

Comment: IE7? That's strange? What DOCTYPE are you using?